# How to generate log files having datetime stamp at each run using log4j2 Properties file

Tags: log4j2

I want to create log files for my Testing framework having datetime stamp for each run of test suites. I trying below code but it is not working.

```
name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename = logs/Temp
appenders = console, file

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %msg%n

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=${filename}/TestRun_%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}.log
appender.fileout = com.veerasundar.dynamiclogger.NewLogForEachRunFileAppender
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %msg%n

loggers=file
logger.file.name=utilities
logger.file.level = debug
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

It is throwing below error when I execute the test suite.

```
2019-06-06 21:57:54,919 main ERROR FileManager (logs/Temp/TestRun_%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}.log) java.io.FileNotFoundException: logs\Temp\TestRun_%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}.log (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect) java.io.FileNotFoundException: logs\Temp\TestRun_%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}.log (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory, the `filename` you have specified was not found.
One can provide `fileName` as some filename and the `filepattern` can be specified explicitly, like this:

```
appender.file.fileName = Testrun.log
appender.file.filePattern = Testrun_%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}.log
```

Comment: I tried above code but now it gives below error in console.


2019-06-07 10:20:21,590 main ERROR File contains an invalid element or attribute "filePattern"

I am very new to this so there might be a silly mistake I am doing I think.

Comment: Can you try the pattern based on what the log4j documentation suggests? 
 http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties

`appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = target/rolling2/test1-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz`

Comment: Thanks susan! I tried above code and it is working. However; later I had to change this to an xml file.